# Is there a way to make a remote GCloud SDK access to Storage object temporarily?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-iam

My aim is to use GCloud SDK in the remote client using something that is supplied by my service. The "something" is what I'm looking for.

In AWS, we use temporary credentials with limited validity. Is there a similar way to do that in GCP. For example, is it possible to generate a temporary bearer token (having the same capabilities as the a service account with limited capabilities that can be given by my service to my remote client to initialize the SDK.

I know that Signed URLs and resumable upload can enable me to operate with Storage to some extent. But using them, I need to implement the clients by myself. Having a token that can be delegated would enable me to use complex set of functionality already implemented in an SDK(say composite objects).

Comment: Have you checked 'short-lived service account credentials' https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-short-lived-service-account-credentials

Answer (score 0):

I would say you are looking for [Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) for Objects in Cloud Storage. Such URLs have embedded authentication information that expires in a given amount of time. So instead of using gsutil cp command, the object can be shared by using the Signed URL.

You can generate those using the Cloud SDK, you can run the command [gsutil signurl](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/signurl).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [IAM conditions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview) on an account (service or user)